# Texture atlas UV coordinate conversion

Tags: textures, coordinate-transformation, texturepacker

I have got some UV coordinates that go from `(0, 0)` to `(16, 16)` for my textures. Now I have packed this texture in a texture atlas with the size `dim (w, h)` at the position `rec (x, y, w, h)`. I need to convert the UV coordinates so that I can address them in the atlas, but my brain has exploded recently and I can't figure it out myself.

**How to convert the coordinates?**

(The idea is to transform the *How* into a texture matrix, so a matrix also counts as answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it myself:

```
translate(rec.x, rec.y)
scale(1 / dim.w, 1 / dim.h)
scale(rec.w / 16, rec.h / 16)

if (invertY)
  scale(1, -1)
  translate(0, dim.h)
```

Note:

- You can combine the two scale operations
- Instead of `/ 16` you can add the dimensions of the unpacked image
- Because of matrices, you will need 3 dimensions and put in z=0 for translations and z=1 for scaling
- Because of matrices, you might need to reverse the operation order